# exact position of the asterisk in a sentence

Tags: punctuation

If I want to annotate a word in the middle of a sentence, should I put the asterisk immediately to its right, or at the end of the sentence?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add examples of the options you consider

Answer (score 3):

Typically the asterisk comes directly to the right of whatever you're annotating.

If you're clarifying the meaning of a specific word, it can go to the right of the word.

If you're clarifying the meaning of an entire sentence, it can go at the end of the sentence as well.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)) provides an uncited assertion that MLA usage holds that it should be placed after the punctuation of the phrase/clause it applies to. The usage I've seen matches your answer above.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Well, if if applies to the phrase/clause, then to the end of that phrase/clause it shall go. But if it applies to a specific word—e.g., there is a sentence about the circadian rhythm in your brain, and the word "zeitgeber" is used, which is a term that is most likely unknown to the general public,—then it would be appropriate to append the explanation to this specific word.

Comment: @tenebris2020 - That would be my interpretation, as well, and consistent with usage I've seen.